# SonarQube Component Tree response data

Tags: sonarqube

I'm having some trouble understanding some of the data in the response from the SonarQube GET api/measures/component_tree API.

Some metrics have a value attribute while others don't. I've figured out that the value displayed in the UI is the "value" unless it does not exist, then the value at the earliest period is used. The other periods are then basically deltas between measurements. Would anyone be able to provide some details around what the response values actually mean? Unfortunately, the actual API documentation that SonarQube provides doesn't give any detail around response data. Specifically, I'm wondering when a value attribute would and would not be there, what the index means since not all have the same indexes (ie. some go 1-4, others have just 3,4), and what the period data represents.

```
 {
    "metric": "new_lines_to_cover",
    "periods": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        "value": "572"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "value": "572"
      },
      {
        "index": 3,
        "value": "8206"
      },
      {
        "index": 4,
        "value": "186574"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "duplicated_lines",
    "value": "80819",
    "periods": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        "value": "-158"
      },
      {
        "index": 2,
        "value": "-158"
      },
      {
        "index": 3,
        "value": "-10544"
      },
      {
        "index": 4,
        "value": "-6871"
      }
    ]
  },
    {
      "metric": "new_line_coverage",
      "periods": [
        {
          "index": 3,
          "value": "3.9900249376558605"
        },
        {
          "index": 4,
          "value": "17.221615720524017"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: what is the version of SonarQube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heuristic is very close from the truth:

- if the metric starts with "new_", it means it's a metric that compute new elements on a period of time. Starting with 6.3, only the [leak period](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/fix-the-leak.html) is supported
- otherwise, the "value" represents the raw value.

For example, to compute the number of issues:

- `violations` computes the total number of issues
- `new_violations` computes the number of new issues on the leak period

To know more about the leak period concept in SonarQube, please check this [article](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/fix-the-leak.html).